# Make issues while installing Fingerprint Feature Extractor software

Tags: linux, make, g++, open-source

I am trying to use an old [software that extracts fingerprint data from an image](https://github.com/FingerJetFXOSE/FingerJetFXOSE). For the life of me, I cannot get the program to compile. I specifically am trying to run the `make` command and build the sample "fjfxSample" binary. I have played with it enough that I've been able to compile the binary, but when I try to execute it, I get a "shared library cannot be opened error".

I am at my wits end. Hopefully someone could tell me what I am doing wrong. The documentation simply states to run "make" and that it is supported on Linux with the proper adjustments to the Makefile. How can I find what the adjustments are so I can successfully use this software?

Comment: Could you please give more information as to what command you are using to run the binary, and what operating system you are using? Could you also post the full output of the "shared library cannot be opened" error?

Comment: the binary is "./fjfxSample". The operating system is Ubuntu server 16, and the error is "./fjfxSample: error while loading shared libraries: libfjfx.so.5: cannot open shared object file: Error 40"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fjfxSample` binary expects its libraries to be found by the dynamic linker. This works if everything is installed, but to run the binary from the build directory without installing it you need to help the linker out:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${PWD}/../lib" ./fjfxSample
```

(assuming you’re running from the `bin` directory in the source tree).